# How do I change the mount point for a ZFS pool?

Tags: zfs

example:

When I created the pool, I set it to mount to /mystorage

```
zpool create -m /mystorage mypool raidz /dev/ada0 dev/ada1 /dev/ada2
```

But now I want the pool to mount to /myspecialfolder.

Any ideas how it can be done? I've searched the net and look at zpool and zfs manpages and found nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
zfs set mountpoint=/myspecialfolder mypool
```

Comment: I didn't realize I can change the mount point while the pool in in use. I thought I needed to export it first and then change the mount point during import. Thank you!

Comment: @mrjayviper If you use the normal commands (not special options like `-F` or similar) and stay away from `destroy`, you cannot do much harm on ZFS. If an operation is not possible, you would get *resource busy*, *dataset in use* or similar. Of course, this is only for the filesystem - your applications may react differently (should handle such events themselves).

Comment: `zfs create -o mountpoint=/myspecialfolder mypool` at create time